# WCF security issue on client side

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I am trying to consume exsting WCF service . I get error -

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Ntlm'.

The authentication header received from the server was:

```
'NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAACgAKADgAAAA1gonic7frIsXfWMkAAAAAAAAAAJ4AngBCAAAABgGxHQAAAA9LAFMAUgBFAFgAAgAKAEsAUwBSAEUAWAABABYASwBTAFIARQBYAC0AVwBFAEIAMAAxAAQAFgBLAFMAUgBFAFgALgBMAE8AQwBBAEwAAwAuAEsAUwBSAEUAWAAtAFcAZQBiADAAMQAuAEsAUwBSAEUAWAAuAEwATwBDAEEATAAFABYASwBTAFIARQBYAC4ATABPAEMAQQBMAAcACAB9bh3UW7vOAQAAAAA
```

I use security  mode="Transport.

My client side configuration is as below:

```
<security mode="Transport"> 

    <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />

 </security>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you expose your web service in IIS, you have to activate Windows Authentication mode in your virtual directory configuration.